# Adding badge number in UItabbarView Controller in runtme

Tags: objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, badge

I am trying to add **badge number** in `UITabBarController` and it is working . But i started NSTimer . when timer completed . it calls webservice and in return i get badge number .

but when i set badge number to `UITabBarController` in this senario . it is no more working.

Comment: Can you include some code with the timer and the connection management please?

Comment: try this UITabBarItem *tbi = (UITabBarItem *)self.tabController.selectedViewController.tabBarItem;
tbi.badgeValue = @"2";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[[super.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:2] tabBarItem].badgeValue = @"1";
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without seeing your code, but two possibilities spring to mind:

1. You're trying to set the badge value from a thread that is not the main thread. Try wrapping your badge value setting code in a `dispatch_async` to the main queue:

   ```
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
   {
       // set badge number    
   });
   ```
2. The item that you're setting the badgeValue on is nil. Try adding a breakpoint or some NSLog statements to the line where you add the badge number, and check the value of some of the objects isn't nil.